# gnome-panel broken with xmonad session in 14.04

Tags: gnome, window-manager, session, xmonad

In 14.04, I've installed both `gnome-session-flashback` and `xmonad`.

- When logging in using `lightdm` and the XMonad+Gnome session, the `gnome-panel` is broken, with half the indicators missing.
- When logging in with a flashback session, and then running `xmonad --replace`, everything works as expected.
- I've tried copying the RequiredComponents line from `/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/gnome-flashback.session` to `xmonad.session` (replacing `metacity` with `xmonad`) but it doesn't help.

I guess something is still missing with my `xmonad.session`. What?

Comment: How did you run "xmonad --replace" under flashback sessions? Tried to run it both in terminal and alt-f2, but ended up with an empty desktop that only respond to right click; the xmonad mod keys were not responsive.

The only usable desktop environment for me was XMonad.

Comment: @iridescent: Ran it from gnome-terminal, without any visible issues.

Comment: For me the panels appear after about two minutes. I have no idéa why.

Comment: I had a similar issue, perpaps this works for you: http://askubuntu.com/a/471459/152895

Comment: @ke.: thanks, did just that myself. I just hate there isn't a proper fix.

Comment: @dacwe: if you're having delayed gnome-panel loading, make sure your startupHook includes gnomeRegister (provided in XMonad.Config.Gnome)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I got xmonad+gnome-panel to work. Tested on Ubuntu 14.04 desktop 64-bit.

1. Install xmonad:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xmonad gnome-panel
   ```
2. Create `~/.xmonad/xmonad.hs` with the following [[1](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Xmonad/Using_xmonad_in_Gnome#Ubuntu)]:

   ```
   import XMonad
   import XMonad.Config.Gnome

   main = do
       xmonad $ gnomeConfig
   ```
3. Select session "GNOME with Xmonad" at lightdm

Hope this helps.

[image: "GNOME with Xmonad"]

Comment: That exactly what I did, as stipulated in my question above. The problem isn't with XMonad, it's with gnome-panel missing half the indicators, and the menu. As if it's configuration wasn't loaded correctly.

Comment: @Shay: I observed that logging into "GNOME with Xmonad" without xmonad.hs will not start gnome-panel by default. Since it was not explicit that you had a xmonad.hs in your question, I (wrongly) assumed that was your problem. Anyway, after the abovementioned steps, logging into "GNOME with Xmonad" starts gnome-panel, and the indicators were exactly the same as those seen in "GNOME Flashback (Metacity)". All observations were made using a fresh install in vmware, which is the most objective reference I could get.

Answer (score 0):

I would install it again by typing in the terminal or from tty type:

```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall xmonad-gnome-panel
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-unity-tweaks

   gsettings set org.settings.gnome-unity-tweake.source false=0
```

and that might make it function again.

Comment: No, that doesn't work. It just reinstalls a broken configuration again.