# No Dropbox indicator icon in "GNOME with Xmonad" session

Tags: 14.04, indicator, dropbox, xmonad

I'm using Ubuntu's "GNOME with Xmonad" session. After switching from 13.10 to 14.04, there was no Dropbox indicator icon in that session, although Dropbox was working fine and the icon appeared in other sessions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a better workaround:

1. Start `gnome-session-properties` and add an entry with the command `xmonad --replace`.
2. Use the "GNOME Flashback (Metacity)" session instead of "GNOME with Xmonad" to login.

Still a bit of a hack, but at least this gives you the Dropbox icon back without stealing the battery icon.

Answer (score 3):

By comparing the sessions in `/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions` and trial and error, I found that the Dropbox icon could be made to reappear by adding the following line at the end of `/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/xmonad.session`:

```
DesktopName=Unity
```

Comment: Turns out this makes the battery icon disappear.